# Plot stacked areas and lines with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to use `ggplot2` to visualize `a, b, c` with `stacked areas` and `ratio_a, ..., ratio_c` with `lines` from the following dataset:

```
   year        a         b         c  ratio_a  ratio_b  ratio_c
0  2010  40533.6  187383.2  173596.0      4.3     12.3      9.8
1  2011  47712.0  220591.6  203260.1      4.5     10.6      8.9
2  2012  52377.0  235319.0  231626.0      4.5      8.1      8.1
3  2013  56957.0  249684.0  262204.0      4.0      7.8      8.3
4  2014  58332.0  271392.0  306739.0      4.1      7.3      8.1
5  2015  60863.0  274278.0  341567.0      3.9      6.0      8.3
6  2016  63671.0  296236.0  384221.0      3.3      6.1      7.8
7  2017  65468.0  334623.0  427032.0      3.9      6.1      8.0
8  2018  64734.0  366000.9  469574.6      3.5      5.8      7.6
9  2019  70467.0  386165.0  534233.0      3.1      5.7      6.9
```

I have used:

```
df_m <- melt(df, id.vars='year')
ggplot(data = df_m, aes(x = year, y = value) ) + 
  geom_bar(aes(fill = variable), stat = 'identity') + 
  xlab('year') +
  ylab('million')
```

Out:

[image]

How could I modify the code above to achive that? Thanks.

Please note we need to use left and right axis as the scale difference between data is quite huge.

**Update:** output from @KoenV's code:

[image]

Comment: I cleaned up my answer to make it more concise and more to the point for future readers. Maybe it would be good if you removed the plot of my previous answer from your question as it could confuse the reader. Just a suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with the following code:

It is possible to plot different data sets within one call to `ggplot`.
Moreover, you may use the `sec_axis` option in a call to `scale_y_continuous` to set a second axis. The `coeff` variable is used to transform the scale.

In order to change the color of the "ratio_x" lines, you may use `scale_color_manual`

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape)
library(dplyr)

df_m <- melt(df, id.vars='year')

df_m_x <- df_m %>% 
  filter(variable %in% c("a", "b", "c")) 

df_m_ratio_x <- df_m %>% 
  filter(variable %in% c("ratio_a", "ratio_b", "ratio_c")) %>%
  mutate(value = value * 100000)

coeff = 1/100000

ggplot() +
  geom_bar(data = df_m_x,  aes(x = year, y = value, fill = variable), alpha = I(0.8), stat = 'identity') +
  geom_line(data = df_m_ratio_x,  aes(x = year, y = value, col = variable)) +
  xlab('year') +
  # ylab('million') +
  scale_y_continuous(
    # Features of the first axis
    name = "million",
    # Add a second axis and specify its features
    sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*coeff, name = "Ratio")
  ) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("ratio_a" = "#00AFBB", "ratio_b" = "#E7B800", "ratio_c" = "#00AFBB")) +
  theme_minimal()
```

This yields the following graph:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help. Yes, that's why I recommended to use dual axes.

Comment: Another tips, maybe we need to change the colors for `ratio` data's lines.

Comment: My pleasure, glad I could help.

Comment: One more question, when you use dual axes, why do you use `mutate(value = value * 100000)`?

Comment: @ahbon Very simple, just try it without the multiplication ;-)

Comment: Sorry, one more question, I want to add points to lines using `+ geom_point(size = 8)` but it doesn't work, do u know why?

Comment: @ahbon If you add the following line after the call to `geom_line`, then it worked for me: `geom_point(data = df_m_ratio_x,  aes(x = year, y = value, col = variable), size = 8) +`. Please try this.

Comment: I found a new problem,  please take a look `year` axis, the values aren't `int`.

Comment: The problem solved by `scale_x_continuous(breaks = min(df_m_x$year):max(df_m_x$year))`, :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
#load packages
require(tidyverse)
require(reshape2)

#read the data
df_dat = read.csv("question1.csv", header = TRUE)

#melt the data
df_dat1 = melt(df_dat, id.vars = c("year"))
df_dat1 = df_dat1 %>%
  mutate(
    vartyp = ifelse(grepl("ratio_",variable),"ratio","volume"),
    year = as.factor(year)
  )

#plotting
df_dat1 %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_area(data = subset(df_dat1, vartyp=="volume"), aes(year, value/100000, group = variable, fill = variable),
            position = "stack", alpha = .6) +
  geom_line(data = subset(df_dat1, vartyp=="ratio"), aes(year, value, group = variable, colour = variable, shape = variable),
            position = "dodge", size = 1) +
  geom_point(data = subset(df_dat1, vartyp=="ratio"), aes(year, value, group = variable, colour = variable, shape = variable),
             position = "dodge", size = 2.5) +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*1, name = "Ratio (in %)")) +
  labs(fill = "Volume", colour = "Ratio", shape = "Ratio") +
  theme_classic()
```

[image: result2]

Comment: Thank you, the stack areas visualization are pretty cool, is it possible to add `ratio`s data as lines?

Comment: Hello. I have modified the code. See if this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

... without reshape ...

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tribble(~year, ~a, ~b, ~c, ~ratio_a,  ~ratio_b, ~ratio_c,
2010,  40533.6,  187383.2,  173596.0,      4.3,     12.3,      9.8,
2011,  47712.0,  220591.6,  203260.1,      4.5,     10.6,      8.9,
2012,  52377.0,  235319.0,  231626.0,      4.5,      8.1,      8.1,
2013,  56957.0,  249684.0,  262204.0,      4.0,      7.8,      8.3,
2014,  58332.0,  271392.0,  306739.0,      4.1,      7.3,      8.1,
2015,  60863.0,  274278.0,  341567.0,      3.9,      6.0,      8.3,
2016,  63671.0,  296236.0,  384221.0,      3.3,      6.1,      7.8,
2017,  65468.0,  334623.0,  427032.0,      3.9,      6.1,      8.0,
2018,  64734.0,  366000.9,  469574.6,      3.5,      5.8,      7.6,
2019,  70467.0,  386165.0,  534233.0,      3.1,      5.7,      6.9)

df_dat1 <- df %>% 
  pivot_longer(!year, names_to = "variable") %>% 
  mutate(
    vartyp = ifelse(grepl("ratio_",variable),"ratio","volume"),
    year = as.factor(year)
  )

#plotting
df_dat1 %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_area(data = subset(df_dat1, vartyp=="volume"), aes(year, value/100000, group = variable, fill = variable),
            position = position_stack(), alpha = .6) +
  geom_line(data = subset(df_dat1, vartyp=="ratio"), aes(year, value, group = variable, colour = variable),
            position = position_dodge(width = 0), size = 1) +
  geom_point(data = subset(df_dat1, vartyp=="ratio"), aes(year, value, group = variable, colour = variable, shape = variable),
             position = position_dodge(width = 0), size = 2.5) +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*1, name = "Ratio (in %)")) +
  labs(fill = "Volume", colour = "Ratio", shape = "Ratio") +
  theme_classic()
```